# Bounded Second Derivative for a Convex Function Implies Growth Bound on the Funtion

Tags: real-analysis

If we have a twice differentiable function f: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $A < f'' <B$ is a global bound on $f''$ does this imply $|f(a)| \leq C(1 + |a|^2)$ for some $C>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Using the fundemental theorem of calculus twice, we know that $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x \left(f'(0)+ \int_0^t f''(s)\,ds \right)\,dt$. Also it always holds that if $g<h$ then $\int_a^b g < \int_a^b h$. By plugging the inequality $f''<B$ into this, it gives that

$f(x)<f(0)+x f'(0)+\int_0^x \int_0^t B \, ds\,dt $
$=f(0)+f'(0)x+\int_0^x Bt\,dt =f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}Bx^2$

This means that $f(x)$ is bounded above by a quadratic function. Any quadratic can be bounded from above by $C(1+x^2)$, provided $C$ is sufficiently large. Repeat the same process from below and you get your result.